# Using C# generics when converting from C++ program

Tags: c#, c++, generics

I'm converting an old C++ program to C#.   There's a function in the C++ program that looks like this:

```
bool Checkpoints(string inputImageFilename, vector<Point> basePoints)
```

later on it uses it like this . . .

```
int x1 = basePoints[0].x;
int y1 = basePoints[0].y;
int x2 = basePoints[1].x;
int y2 = basePoints[1].y;
```

**vector** is from the STL.
I understand that C# generics are sort of like templates but I've never used generics before.

I've also read that C# will get a generic vector class soon, but in the meantime a list is kind of like a vector, so can I use the System.Drawing Point structure and make a generic list such that I can code something like this? ...

```
bool Checkpoints(string inputImageFilename, MyGenericList<Point> basePoints)
```

...if so, can I access it with array syntax like in the C++ code, or would I have to use an ArrayList for that?

Comment: _"**vector** is from the STL"_ It's not _the STL_ from the last century 90ies! We have the c++ standard library meanwhile.

Comment: ...I said it was old.

Comment: I still don't believe you really mean that specific implementation mentioned here: [tag:STL]. It's a commonly misused term.

Comment: *"C# will get a generic vector class soon"* --> oh, it's already [there](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn858385.aspx), but it doesn't mean the same thing *at all*. It's used for SIMD. `List<T>` is the direct equivalent of `std::vector<T>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `List<T>` or at least implement `IList<T>` if you use your own. Those both have the indexer defined.

You could just accept `IList<T>` and that will even work with arrays out of the box!

```
bool Checkpoints(string inputImageFilename, IList<Point> basePoints)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I've also read that C# will get a generic vector class soon, but in
>   the meantime a list is kind of like a vector, so can I use the
>   System.Drawing Point structure and make a generic list such that I can
>   code something like this? ...

You can use

```
bool Checkpoints(string inputImageFilename, List<Point> basePoints)
```

And indeed you can access members using similar say [] syntax. Make sure the point class in C# is similar to the one you use in C++ though.

You can keep in mind also in C# terms the list object will be reference type while the vector (as used in C++) is value type.